# jQuery toggle all paragraphs by 1 button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm trying to achieve a toggle open/close all paragraph elements effect when clicking the last button (Toggle All). This is the first time I try to use jQuery and even though it seems pretty straightforward, it's not working as I hoped for it too.

**This is my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggleAll p").click(function() {
    $(".toggleAcronym").toggle(slow);
  });
});
```

```css
#p6Acronyms {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

#p6Acronyms button {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(0, 152, 223);
  color: azure;
}

#p6Acronyms button:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 47, 255);
  color: antiquewhite;
}

#p6Acronyms p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="p6Acronyms">
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">RWE</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Real World Example</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">CRUD</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Create, Read, Update, Delete</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">CNS</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Central Nervous System</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">MPS</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Muscle Protein Synthesis</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">I.e.</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">In essence</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">ALAP</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">As Long As Possible</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">AMAP</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">As Much As Possible</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">CoC</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Contents of Consciousness</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">RR(P)(F)-R</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Risk Reward (Probability)(Fragility) - Ratio</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">AoL</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Area of Life (=Intellectual, Physical, Relationships & Intellectual)</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">MBS</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Mind Body & Spirit</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">QoC</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Quality of Consciousness</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">PFC</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Pre-Frontal Cortex</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">SRV</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Survival & Reproduction Value. //(Often used to describe factors with directional effect on this.)</p>
    <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">P/T-R</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Practice/Theory-Ratio</p>
    <button id="toggleAll"><h2>Toggle All</h2></button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">This button toggles all acronym descriptions to Show/Hide</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There is no child p element of your buttons. `"#toggleAll p"` says find all p elements that are (indirect) children of the element with the id of toggleAll

Answer (score 1):

You was so close, the "slow" argument passed to the `toggle()` method must be between quotes like :

```
$(".toggleAcronym").toggle('slow');
___________________________^____^
```

And you need to attach the click event to the button instead of the paragraph inside it like :

```
$("#toggleAll").click(function() {
```

Instead of :

```
$("#toggleAll p").click(function() {
______________^ Should be removed
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggleAll").click(function() {
    $(".toggleAcronym").toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#p6Acronyms {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

#p6Acronyms button {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(0, 152, 223);
  color: azure;
}

#p6Acronyms button:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 47, 255);
  color: antiquewhite;
}

#p6Acronyms p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p6Acronyms">
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">RWE</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Real World Example</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">CRUD</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Create, Read, Update, Delete</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">CNS</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Central Nervous System</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">MPS</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Muscle Protein Synthesis</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">I.e.</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">In essence</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">ALAP</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">As Long As Possible</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">AMAP</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">As Much As Possible</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">CoC</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Contents of Consciousness</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">RR(P)(F)-R</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Risk Reward (Probability)(Fragility) - Ratio</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">AoL</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Area of Life (=Intellectual, Physical, Relationships & Intellectual)</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">MBS</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Mind Body & Spirit</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">QoC</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Quality of Consciousness</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">PFC</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Pre-Frontal Cortex</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">SRV</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Survival & Reproduction Value. //(Often used to describe factors with directional effect on this.)</p>
  <button onclick="oneElmToggle(this)">P/T-R</button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">Practice/Theory-Ratio</p>
  <button id="toggleAll"><h2>Toggle All</h2></button>
  <p class="toggleAcronym">This button toggles all acronym descriptions to Show/Hide</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it is working and I understand why. Can't seem to get it to work in my project though. Do I have to include the jQuery script link in every html file or is enough to leave it under the package.json dependencies of the project after npm installing it in the folder of the project? What am I missing?